# How to write on output cell of jupyter notebook in vscode

Tags: python, machine-learning, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, kaggle

I wanted to download Kaggle datasets directly from jupyter notebook in vscode. But while running the code to download the dataset it requires a Kaggle username and which needs to be given in the output of that running cell. But I can't figure out a way to write on that output cell of the jupyter notebook in vscode. I am attaching the below screenshot to get a better understanding of the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you get the pop up at the top of the screen (Press 'Enter' to confirm or 'Escape' to cancel)? You type your Kaggle username there.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you. It is camouflaged in my dark theme. It is solved.

Comment: consider accepting this as the answer